# Case insensitive search in Elastic Search

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

I have a String field in this string field for example we have data as INDIA

But when I search with "`india`" instead of INDIA ,I am not getting any response

Here is my Query of elastic search, I don't want to use analyzer (lower case),I want to do explicitly from  search query is there any way to sort this out

```
{
   "query" : {
       "match" : {
          "BrandName" : {
              "query" : "india",
              "type" : "boolean"
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to search in a case-insensitive way, you need to build your index accordingly. Not much you can do if the index does not match your search requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply 
so it's necessary to define custom analyzer in setting and use this in mapping? no other way to handle this in query builder ?     I was looking for replica of SQL Lower case function in elastic search.

Comment: What's the mapping of your `BrandName` field?

Comment: "BrandName": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed",
                  "fields": {
                     "raw": {
                        "type": "string"
                     }
                  },

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found the solution

The query string query works fine for this purpose

```
{
   "query" : {
       "query_string": {
      "default_field": "BrandName",
      "query": "india"
    }
    }
}
```

This will hit the documents which content Brand Name as INDIA as well